# Implementing a thread safe exponential gauge

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am implementing a java based exponential gauge that will have an initial value (say 1.0) and will decay exponentially in time to 0. another function will increase the gauge value time to time. Now I need some help to develop it thread safe.

I am thinking of java timer or executor to create the decay functionality that will decrease the value of the gauge every 5 millisecond. In the same time another function, when get called will increase the value.

Now I am assuming that it will have issue with concurrency so need help to implement it correctly.

My questions are:

1. How can I design a class that will execute the function to decrease the value every 5 millisecond.
2. How can I make it thread safe so that other thread can update the same variable.

Any help??

Comment: Have you looked at [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be concurrency on the gauge variable.

Use a Thread Safe implementation such as an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to hold the value. Multiple threads can safely update this variable concurrently.

For the function decreasing the value, use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). The method [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) will let you specify a period.

(note: you can implement synchronization by declaring your variable volatile, but before you embark into this, make sure you fully understand the implications and pitfalls such as running `var++`)